# exception handling in decorator function

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, decorator

New to Python and I have a bunch of functions to perform various tasks on some hardware. Each function has different numbers of parameters and returns.

I want to make a kind of generic "retry" wrapper function that will catch an exception from any of my functions and do some error handling (such as retrying the task).

From what I understand I should be able to use a decorator function as a generic wrapper for each of my functions. That seems to work, but I don't seem to be able to actually get any of the exceptions from the function being called from within my decorator function.

I've looked at various examples and come up with this:

```
def retry(function):
    def _retry(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            reply = function(*args, **kwargs)
            print "reply: ", reply
            return reply
        except PDError as msg:
            print "_retry", msg
        except:
            print "_retry: another error"
    return _retry
```

Then I call it using the name of one of my functions:

```
value = retry(pd.command_get_parameter(0x00))
```

It seems to call my function and return correctly, but the exceptions are never caught within my retry function. So I can't handle an error and do a retry.

I've also tried this:

```
from functools import wraps

def retry(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def _retry(*args, **kwargs):
    .....
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or if this is even the best way to be doing this. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this? I don't really want to have to make separate "retry" functions for each of my main functions.

Comment: Did you mean `retry(pd.command_get_parameter)(0x00)`? Right now you're passing the result of `pd.command_get_parameter(0x00)` to `retry` as `function`.

Comment: @Will: You should be using like: `@retry def command_get_parameter(..)`. You can also pass in a function like `retry(command_get_parameter)` and use the returned function in its place. You are not doing either of them. You are passing in the returned value from `command_get_parameter(..)` to retry -- where you should be passing in a function.

Comment: @Ryan: Thank you. Now that you have explained it I can see why it didn't work as I was passing the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer:

You should be using like:

```
def retry(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def _retry(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            reply = function(*args, **kwargs)
            print "reply: ", reply
            return reply
        except PDError as msg:
            print "_retry", msg
        except:
            print "_retry: another error"
    return _retry

class SomeClass(object):

    @retry
    def command_get_parameter(..):
        return <some value>
s = SomeClass()
result = s.command_get_parameter(..)  #retry(..) actually invokes this function.
```

Decorators take in a function, and return a *decorated* function. A decoration is something that is capable of doing something before the function is invoked, after it, or catch exceptions etc. If you the above syntax (`@retry)`, the interpreter call the `retry(..)`, passes in the function object (`command_get_parameter`), and replaces the function with the function returned by `retry(command_get_parameter)`.

What's going on is *somewhat* similar to below steps (pseudocode):

```
new_command_get_parameter = retry(command_get_parameter) #@retry has this effect.
result = new_command_get_parameter(your_input)
```

The difference is the above two steps are done done for you by the interpreter magically -- keeping the code cleaner and readable for the eyes.

---

Currently you are invoking the function, and passing the result of it to `retry(..)` which is obviously wrong. Further it wont catch exceptions the way you want it to.

---

**Update**: If you want the retry to access the instance variable, all you have to do is let `_retry` use the first parameter as `self`. Something like:

```
def retry(func):
    def _retry(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Decorator printing a:", self.a
        print "Decorator printing b:", self.b
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print "Caught exception"
            return "Grr.."
    return _retry


class Temp(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @retry
    def command(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "In command."
        print "Args:", args
        print "KWargs:", kwargs

        raise Exception("DIE!")

t = Temp(3, 5)

print t.command(3,4,5, a=4, b=8)
```

**Output**:

```
Decorator printing a: 3
Decorator printing b: 5
In command.
Args: (4, 5)
KWargs: {'a': 4, 'b': 8}
Caught exception
Grr..
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if I was to make "retry" part of the "SomeClass" in your example, how do I define it?

For example:
    class SomeClass(object):

        @retry
        def retry(self, function):
            try:
                reply = function(*args, **kwargs)
                return reply
            except:
                #handle error

Do I need @wraps(function)

Comment: I don't think I was clear on my last question. Is it possible to make the retry function part of the SomeClass class? For example I'd need this if as part of the retry mechanism I needed to call a different function in SomeClass.

Here is what I tried but it isn't valid:

`code`
class SomeClass(object):

    def retry(self, function):
        @wraps(function)
        def _retry(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                reply = function(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: @Will: Not in the same class, because 1) interpreter needs the definition of retry function (because it is going to execute it immediately after it is defined. 2) `retry` function is not available until the interpreter is done parsing the class. I'll update my answer with the closest you can get.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you.